# JSFiddle - Website blank hidden space

Tags: html, css, image, web, jsfiddle

I'm currently trying to make a new design for my website. I got to this point, but I cannot find out how to remove the blank space to the right of the picture (slide the webpage to the right and you see it, a huge blank space).

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yscu95hb/1/

And here is part of the code that I think I have to change.

```
#conteudo {
    top: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px 15px 0px 260px;
}

.images {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100vw - 260px);
    align-content: center;
}

.images img {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 35px);
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 990;
}
```

Can anyone help me?
Thank you.

-- edit --

I already posted the code that shows the image but I cannot make it to center. Any suggestions?

Comment: You clearly saw the message about linking to JS Fiddle without posting your [mcve] code here in your question, and rather than choosing to post code you instead tried to work around that limitation. Why? If you want us to help you then why not help us, by posting the (minimum) relevant code in your question where it should be?

Comment: Here it is, the code I think that is affecting the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason you see the "white" space on the right side is the css you are applying to your `#conteudo` element.

This is your css for the element:

```
#conteudo {
    top: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px 15px 0px 260px;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

there are multiple ways to fix this. one way would be to remove the margin attribute or change the width to something lower than 100vw.
What you are doing is saying the element should be as wide as the browser window (100% of the window width) and then also saying that outside that width it should have more margin (in your case 15px on the right and 260px on the left), and that is "streching the page", causing the total widht to be larger than window width.

Comment: So which modification would you suggest to improve the code and keep the same design (excluding the big blank space on the right)?

Comment: Well, after changing a lot of times I got it to remove the space, but I cannot center the images... (when window is resized)

And I updated the jsfiddle with the new code!

Answer (score -1):

Add [Eric Meyers resets](https://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/) to the top of your css file. It removes all styling that the browser automatically includes such as margin and padding. It seems like alot and most of it will go unused, but its nice to have all of it just in case.

Its good practice to have a set of resets at the beginning of every webpage and from my experience this one is the best.

Comment: I added it to the top of the CSS and just removed the spaces before the menu options of the sidebar....